# CS50X Week 4: FILTER (less) BLUR Funtion

Tags: c, loops, filter, cs50

When I put sumRed.. outside loop: it's still blur but I think have something wrong in here.
When I put sumRed.. inside loop: it correct.

??? I don't know what's diferences between sumRed outside loop and sumRed inside loop ? Please help.

******* SUMRED - OUTSIDE LOOP ***********

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Create a temp 2-dimension array: to calculator average of sum each pixel in matrix[3x3].
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

    for ( int i = 0; i < height ; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < width ; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    float sumRed = 0;
    float sumGreen = 0;
    float sumBlue = 0;
    float count = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < height ; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < width ; j++)
        {
            for ( int h = i -1 ; h < i + 2; h ++)
            {
                if ( h < 0 || h > height)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                for ( int w = j - 1 ; w < j + 2 ; w++)
                {
                    if ( w < 0 || w > width)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    sumRed = sumRed + temp[h][w].rgbtRed;
                    sumGreen = sumGreen + temp[h][w].rgbtGreen;
                    sumBlue = sumBlue + temp[h][w].rgbtBlue;
                    count ++;
                }
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round (sumRed / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round (sumGreen / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round (sumBlue / count);

        }
    }

    return;
}
```

******** SUMRED - INSIDE LOOP *******

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Create a temp 2-dimension array: to calculator average of sum each pixel in matrix[3x3].
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

    for ( int i = 0; i < height ; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < width ; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < height ; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < width ; j++)
        {

            float sumRed = 0;
            float sumGreen = 0;
            float sumBlue = 0;
            float count = 0;

            for ( int h = i -1 ; h < i + 2; h ++)
            {
                if ( h < 0 || h > height)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                for ( int w = j - 1 ; w < j + 2 ; w++)
                {
                    if ( w < 0 || w > width)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    sumRed = sumRed + temp[h][w].rgbtRed;
                    sumGreen = sumGreen + temp[h][w].rgbtGreen;
                    sumBlue = sumBlue + temp[h][w].rgbtBlue;
                    count ++;
                }
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round (sumRed / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round (sumGreen / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round (sumBlue / count);

        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Now would be a great time to learn how to use a debugger; then you could *see* what the difference is.